# Aptana Folding/Collapsing javascript code

Tags: javascript, aptana

I need to be able to fold/collapse various code fragments throughout my javascript, kind of like #region #endregion in C#.  I can't find a way to do this, any help?

Answer (score 2):

Window menu -> select Preferences -> expand Aptana -> expand Editors -> expand JavaScript -> select Folding.