# Eclipse Aptana Javascript custom folding via #region and #endregion

Tags: javascript, eclipse, aptana, dtd, folding

I've read the following similar topics:

- [Aptana Folding/Collapsing javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356902/aptana-folding-collapsing-javascript-code)
- [Regions/code collapse in JavaScript? (Aptana studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377930/regions-code-collapse-in-javascript-aptana-studio)

The answers however do not satisfy me. I want to decide where Aptana should do the folds I need. Waiting gazillions of years until the Aptana guys even start thinking about this is not an option.

Most of the editors save the folding stuff in a .dtd file. Does somebody knows how I can bring in region folding points myself?